# How to align items of a list CSS/jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a simple dropdown menu ONLY with jquery (actually, the CSS is built-into the jquery, onload). 
Everything looks pretty good, except that the items from the second list, are displaying over the items from the first list.

**DEMO:** http://getyourbots.com/stackoverflow/jquery/

**Here is my code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Jquery</title>
        <script src="jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
        <script>
                        window.onload = function() {
                $('ul').css({
                    'list-style' : 'none',
                                        'margin':'0',
                                        'padding':'0'

                });
                                $('ul li').css({
                    'float' : 'left',
                    'width' : '150px',
                                        'height' : '30px',
                                        'text-align' : 'center',
                                        'background' : '#003399',
                                        'font-size' : '20px',
                                        'padding':'9px',
                                       // 'margin':'10px'
                });
                                $('ul li li').css({

                                        'margin':'0 auto'

                                        //'top':'50px',

                                        //'padding':'5px'

                                        //'margin':'10px'
                });
                                $('ul li a').css({
                    'text-decoration' : 'none',
                                        'color':'white'
                });


            };
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('li').hover(function(){
                    $(this).find('ul>li').fadeToggle(600);
            });
             $('li').mouseenter(function(){
                     $(this).css({
            'background' : 'green'
                    });
            });
            $('li').mouseleave(function(){
                     $(this).css({
            'background' : '#003399'
                    });
            }); 
        });
        </script>
        <style>



        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a>            
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">How it started</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Our team</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sponsors</a></li>
                </ul></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a>
            <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Programming</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated. I know it's just a line of code, but I've tried everything with positioning.

Comment: Try to design it using css only and then use jQuery, it will likely be a lot faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ul > li {position: relative;}
ul ul {position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

They're appearing under the < a > tag rather than below the < li > block because the < li > block is set to float.

What you need to do is use css style: clear:both to make the < li > element take up its desired space

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by adding `position: relative;` to your top level `<li>` elements and adding `position: absolute; top: 100%;` to your `<ul>` elements that are the drop downs.

**Additional JQuery**

```
$('ul li').css({
    'position' : 'relative'
});
$('ul li ul').css({
    'position' : 'absolute',
    'top' : '100%'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a margin-top to your $('ul li').css()

```
$('ul li').css({
  'float' : 'left',
  'width' : '150px',
  'height' : '30px',
  'text-align' : 'center',
  'background' : '#003399',
  'font-size' : '20px',
  'padding':'9px',
  'margin-top':'15px' //added this, tested your site w/ chrome and it works for me
});
```